# How to remove zero values until the first non-zero value occurs in an R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

The title says it all! I have grouped data where I'd like to remove rows up until the first 0 `value` by `id` group.

Example code:

```
problem <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
  value = c(0,0,2,0,0,8,4,2,1,7,6,5)
)


solution <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
  value = c(2,0,8,4,2,1,7,6,5)
)
```

Comment: By *"I'd like to remove columns"* you mean rows? Why do the first 2 rows get removed?

Comment: And why is it `c(2,0,8 ...)` instead of `c(2,0,0,8 ...)`

Comment: I meant rows, yes

Comment: "And why is it c(2,0,8 ...) instead of c(2,0,0,8 …)"
Are you asking why my example dataset has the values it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
problem %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(first_match = min(row_number()[value != 0])) %>% 
  filter(row_number() >= first_match) %>% 
  select(-first_match) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 9 x 2
     id value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     1     0
3     2     8
4     2     4
5     2     2
6     3     1
7     3     7
8     3     6
9     3     5
```

Or more succinctly per Tjebo's comment:

```
problem %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number() >= min(row_number()[value != 0])) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: that's nice, but you could basically leave out the mutate line entirely and use `min(etc)` in `filter` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base `R`:

```
subset(problem,ave(value,id,FUN=cumsum)>0)
#    id value
# 3   1     2
# 4   1     0
# 6   2     8
# 7   2     4
# 8   2     2
# 9   3     1
# 10  3     7
# 11  3     6
# 12  3     5
```

Use `abs(value)` if you have negative values in your real case.